Do Google Cloud Task requests count towards concurrent requests in Google App Engine?
Google App Engine (Standard) has a max_concurrent_requests setting that says:

The number of concurrent requests an automatic scaling instance can
accept before the scheduler spawns a new instance

My question is: when a Google Cloud Task forwards a request to a handler in App Engine, does that count as a concurrent request?
If a Cloud Task sends a request to App Engine, and that task is doing some long running operation (say for 10 minutes), is that counted as a max_concurrent_requests? Which, in turn, would cause more App Engine instances to spin up as more handlers started by Cloud Tasks are currently running?


when a Google Cloud Task forwards a request to a handler in App Engine, does that count as a concurrent request?

Yes, As stated in the Documentation

The Cloud Tasks service also forwards the task request to the handler, but this worker is located within the App Engine.

Although the request is triggered by Cloud Task, the request is handled by App Engine Instance.
So as per the Documentation if the number of concurrent requests reaches a value equal to max_concurrent_requests times target_throughput_utilization, the scheduler tries to start a new instance.
